# Studies on Android users' attitude to security

Tags: privacy, professional-education, android

I'm a final year BSc. student of Computer Security & Forensics at the University of Bedfordshire (UK). I'm investigating perceptions of security on Android platforms, and how to  educate users of the need to use good security practices and products to protect their devices and data.

I'm looking for links to academic research on Android users' attitudes, perceptions, and behavior regarding security, and for data about Android users' perceptions and experiences (good and bad) of security-related incidents where Android devices have been involved.

Comment: Do IOS users? I hear "IOS doesn't have any exploits or malware" all the time.

Comment: I think that the question you've asked (a) won't get the answers you want and (b) isn't a good fit for SE.  You've asked a subjective question with a perjorative undertone, but you seem to be looking for links to research.  Take a look at the FAQ, particularly the section around "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions . . . " and please revise.  I don't mean to be harsh about this - I think that there is a very interesting /useful question underneath.

Comment: I agree with Mark. As it stands, this question doesn't adhere to StackExchange standards as specified in the FAQ. I've flagged to close. If you edit your question to something with has an objective answer and doesn't solicit lists or opinion, then I'd be happy to let it remain here.

Comment: @ewanm89 No exploits on iOS? Please excuse me whilst I laugh my ass off! :P

Comment: @ewanm89 Anything can be exploited even Macs, which people have the same mentality. The reasons Mac gained this mentality was because the shortage of users, iOS has the second biggest share in the 'smart' phone market and is also prone to exploitation.

Comment: I agree with @Polynomial agreeing with MarkC.Wallace. I think these kinds of sociological studies could be interesting and useful, but the SE network of sites was designed in such a way that the question doesn't really fit here.

Comment: @Polynomial exactly what I do every time, that is why it is in quotes.

Comment: I think the question is now more suitable for Security.SE in its current state (given all the edits that have been made).

Answer (score 5):

I don't have any experience of any security related incidents personally but I have found some references to help you out a bit.

1. Why Eve and Mallory Love Android: An Analysis of Android SSL (In)Security
   http://www2.dcsec.uni-hannover.de/files/android/p50-fahl.pdf
2. French cops cuff man over €500K Android Trojan scam
    http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/10/19/french_android_trojan_suspect_arrested/
3. Lookout Security  <-- Perhaps the leaders in mobile security

   https://www.lookout.com
4. Nice IEEE published paper <-- might need to be on a Uni network to gain access
   http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4768655&tag=1

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  I suggest editing your answer to focus on user attitudes. *"Why Eve and Mallory Love Android..."*: this is the most relevant, but it only looks at whether users can recognize whether users of the Android browser can recognize whether they are on a HTTPS page.  *"French cops.."*: this has nothing to do with user attitudes, perception, or behavior. *"Lookout"*: a link to a company's home page is not helpful (and is frankly a bit spammy). *"IEEE published paper"*: this paper has nothing to do with user attitudes, perception, or behavior.

Comment: But I'm assuming a lot of the research he is going to undertake would be around security hence the links are to security providers / security news. The second link shows that there are vulnerabilities and users are getting effected by those. The lookout security link has a nice in depth blog that brings up more security issues etc. and the IEEE paper is about understanding security issues and hence will form an important role in further research. If these have been shown it forms an outline that there are security issues and they have been acknowledged but that many users aren't aware of these

Answer (score 4):

For information about attitudes, perceptions, and behaviors of Android users, I recommend the following research papers:

- [Measuring User Confidence in Smartphone Security and Privacy](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~afelt/chin-soups17.pdf), Erika Chin, Adrienne Porter Felt, Vyas Sekar, and David Wagner, SOUPS 2012.
- [Android Permissions: User Attention, Comprehension, and Behavior](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~afelt/felt-androidpermissions-soups.pdf), Adrienne Porter Felt, Elizabeth Ha, Serge Egelman, Ariel Haney, Erika Chin, and David Wagner, SOUPS 2012.
- [Attitudes to IT Security when Using a Smartphone](http://fedcsis.org/proceedings/fedcsis2012/pliks/207.pdf), Zinaida Benenson, Olaf Kroll-Peters, and Matthias Krupp, FedCSIS 2012.
- [A Conundrum of Permissions: Installing Applications on an Android Smartphone](http://infosecon.net/usec12/papers/kelley-usec12.pdf), Patrick Kelley, Sunny Consolvo, Lorrie Cranor, Jaeyeon Jung, Norman Sadeh, David Wetherall, USEC 2012.
- [Poster: Cellphones and Punishment: Encouraging Secure Mobile Behavior Through Morality](http://cups.cs.cmu.edu/soups/2012/posters/soups12_posters-vanbruggen.pdf), Dirk Van Bruggen, Shu Liu, Aaron Striegel, Chuck Crowell, and John D'Arcy, SOUPS 2012 poster session.
- [I've Got 99 Problems, But Vibration Ain't One: A Survey of Smartphone Users' Concerns](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~afelt/spsm4003-felt.pdf), 
  Adrienne Porter Felt, Serge Egelman, and David Wagner, SPSM 2012.
- [Short Paper: Enhancing Users’ Comprehension of Android Permissions](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~vinodg/papers/spsm2012/spsm2012.pdf), Liu Yang, Nader Boushehrinejadmoradi, Pallab Roy, Vinod Ganapathy, and Liviu Iftode, SPSM 2012.
- [Short Paper: Enhancing Mobile Application Permissions with Runtime Feedback and Constraints](http://appanalysis.org/jjung/jaeyeon-pub/spsm4018s-jung.pdf), Jaeyeon Jung, Seungyeop Han, David Wetherall, SPSM 2012.
- [Choice Architecture and Smartphone Privacy: There's A Price for That](http://www.guanotronic.com/~serge/papers/weis12.pdf), Serge Egelman, Adrienne Porter Felt, and David Wagner, WEIS 2012.
- [Smart Phone Use by Non-Mobile Business Users](http://collablab.northwestern.edu/patti/pubs/MobileHCI2011-BaoEtAl_SmartPhoneUse.pdf), Patti Bao, Jeffrey Pierce, Stephen Whittaker, and Shumin Zhai, MobileHCI 2011.
- [No smart phone is an island: The impact of places, situations, and other devices on smart phone use](http://domino.watson.ibm.com/library/cyberdig.nsf/papers/F5FD878B5B062ACA85257635004EC3F5/%24File/rj10452.pdf), Tara Matthews, Jeffrey Pierce, and John Tang.

As you can see, there has recently been a lot of interest in this topic, and there is a growing research literature on this subject.  I'm sure we'll continue to see more research in this area in the near future.